# Android touch events get filtered out?

Tags: android, events, touch

I wrote an Android application that capture all TouchEvents( e.g.,DOWN, UP, MOVE..) and dump it to a log file.

The application works fine with real human touches, at the speed of 1->5 touches per second.  However, when I use a mechanical touch generator running at speed around 100->500 touches per second, the log file shows less number of touches than I actually generated.

After looking at the touches recorded in the log file with timestamps of each touch event, I found a very strange pattern of event captures by the application. There is always 2 consecutive events which are 2 milliseconds apart, followed by another event after about 50ms.

For example: 
   1st event occured at 10th milliseconds

2nd event occured at 12th milliseconds,which is 2 milliseconds after the first

3rd event occured at 62th milliseconds, which is 50 milliseconds after the first

4th event occured at 64th milliseconds, which is 2 milliseconds after the first

then the next event occured at 104th millisecond ... and then 106th ... and so on

I have searched around about the issue with no luck. However I found that Android allows double touches, but doesn't allow more than 2 consecutive touches. Which means you can have 2 consecutive touch very close to each other, but no more than 2. My guess is the screen driver disable the 3rd, 4th.... touch even for a period of time (very likely 50 milliseconds), untill it allows the next event happens again. The reason for it to do that is it assumes human can not touch too fast and such kind of touch should be disabled and considered as error/noise.
Note that this is different from multitouch, since I am talking about consecutive events happens at different point in time (even though those are very close) at a very fast rate rather than multiple touch events happen at the same time in multitouch.

I would like to ask if any one know why there is such filtering mechanism ? and how to disable them if it is at all possible ? My goal is trying to record as many touch events at as high rate as possible.

I would really appreciate if any one could confirm/fasify my hypothesis or help me to go around the filter that android employs.

Thanks a lot for reading all the way to this point :).

Comment: Android processes touch events as much as it can do extra work on the UI thread. What is this mechanical time generator? Never heard of it. Could what your observing have anything to do with time slicing? remember that, the UI thread has to share the CPU with other threads, and your process is just one of many.

Comment: My mechanical touch generator is just a rotating wheel with capacitive hammer on it, tapping onto the screen at high speed. When I have 5 hammers on the wheel and rotate the wheel at speed of 100 round per second, it would generate 500 touch per second.

Could you explain more about limit of processing event that the device can do ?

By the way I am testing on Samsung 10.1 Galaxy Tab, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you found a solution for this yet, however I recently ran into the same thing. I was getting stack traces printed to Logcat stating that too many threads were accessing the same log file (this makes sense, because every time you write to a file, it automatically runs it on a new thread). My solution was to simply put all the logs into an array of a few hundred Strings, and when the array reached its max size, use `StringBuilder` to append all the logs and write them (one thread) to my file. This fixed all of my problems.